# "Plus, ..." at the beginning of a sentence. Is it usual and / or always correct?

Tags: word-usage

Does it sound usual to use "Plus" at the beginning of a sentence to say "moreover" or "furthermore" or it is a form to use only in specific cases ? I'm wondering because I don't see it much. (And I don't hear it too, but I'm in France so ...)

If so, would it be always correct to replace "moreover" by "plus" in that context, or not ?

Here is a simple example :

> I don't want to tell him the truth because (...).
>   Plus, I don't like him.

Maybe is it better to use it when writing, or is it ok when speaking too ?

Comment: Not OK in writing outside of narrative dialogue. Not particularly commonly used in speech either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A conjunction at the beginning of a sentence is perfectly grammatical for most contemporary readers, although it was deprecated by several generations of schoolmarmish stylists. You're perfectly safe using *and*, *but* or *or* there. Keep in mind, however, that they are conjunctions, not adverbs, and should not be separated from the clause they introduce with a comma, unless that comma is the first bracketing a parenthetical remark.

*Plus*, however, is another matter. Use of *plus* in any but the mathematical sense is distinctly colloquial. It may be employed as a conjunction in the chattier sort of business or technical writing, but this should be avoided in academic contexts.

Answer (score 5):

As a native AmE speaking non-scholar (read: "Joe Schmoe"):

The use of `plus` in the context you provided is fitting for a relaxed, *informal relationship* with the person that you are speaking or writing to. This context is the **only** time I would personally use `plus`, in any other context including professional communications I would use `Also, ...` to replace `Plus, ...`.